# Read files inside a folder from a path

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I need to read all files inside a folder. Here's my path c:/records/today/ and inside path there are two files data1.txt and data2.txt. After getting the files, I need to read and display it.
I already did with the first file, I just don't know how to do both.

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("c:/records/today/data1.txt");        
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: So what stops you to do the same thing with the second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can use this to check child paths isFile or directory

```
Arrays.stream(ResourceUtils.getFile("c:/records/today/data1.txt").listFiles())
            .filter(File::isFile)
            .forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
                    System.out.println(content);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("c:\\records\\today\\data1.txt");
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 0):

To read all the files in specific folder, you can do it somewhat like below:

```
File dir = new File("c:/records/today");      
for (File singleFile: dir.listFiles()) {
    // do file operation on singleFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code slightly, and instead of using Resources.getFile use Files.walk to return a stream of files and iterate over them.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("c:\\records\\today\)).forEach(x->{
        try {
            if (!Files.isDirectory(x))
            System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(x));
            //Add internal folder handling if needed with else clause
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Add some exception handling as required
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```